# How to crop/cut parts of Tikz image properly

Tags: tikz-pgf

### I have got the following image:

[image]

### I want to cut it like this, but without rectangles filled white, because they leave "blank" space between the actual picture and text.

[image]

### There is already an answer, using \clip. Here is an edited code:

```
\documentclass[leqno,10pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
    Illum beatae soluta aliquid beatae velit et. Sit minus alias unde et enim reprehenderit quis odit. Iusto saepe et iure animi. Laborum at voluptas doloremque tempore et ut ullam consectetur.

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \clip (-2,-2.7) rectangle (9.5,2.7);
        \draw[-] (-2, 0) -- (9.3, 0);
        \draw[->, line width=0.3mm] (9.2999, 0) -- (9.3, 0);
        \coordinate[label=below left:\small$C$] (C) at (-0.863, 0); \fill (C) circle (1pt);
        \coordinate[label=below right:\small$A$] (A) at (8.137, 0); \fill (A) circle (1pt);
        \coordinate[label=above:\small$B$] (B) at (3.637, 4.5); \fill (B) circle (1pt);
        \coordinate[label=below:\small$D$] (D) at (3.637, -4.5); \fill (D) circle (1pt);
        \draw[-] (3.637, 4.5) -- (3.637, -4.5);

        \coordinate[label=below right:\small$A_1$] (A1) at (5.887, 0); \fill (A1) circle (1pt);
        \coordinate[label=below right:\small$A_2$] (A2) at (4.762, 0); \fill (A2) circle (1pt);

        \coordinate[label=above right:\small$B_1$] (B1) at (3.637, 2.25); \fill (B1) circle (1pt);
        \coordinate[label=above right:\small$B_2$] (B2) at (3.637, 1.125); \fill (B2) circle (1pt);

        \coordinate[label=below left:\small$D_1$] (D1) at (3.637, -2.25); \fill (D1) circle (1pt);
        \coordinate[label=below left:\small$D_2$] (D2) at (3.637, -1.125); \fill (D2) circle (1pt);

        \coordinate[label=below left:\small$C_1$] (C1) at (1.387, 0); \fill (C1) circle (1pt);
        \coordinate[label=below left:\small$C_2$] (C2) at (2.512, 0); \fill (C2) circle (1pt);

        \draw[-] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (A1) -- (B1) -- (C1) -- (D1) -- (A2) -- (B2) -- (C2) -- (D2) -- (4.1995, 0) -- (3.637, 0.5625) -- (3.076, 0) -- (3.637, -0.5625) -- (3.9182, 0) -- (3.637, 0.28125) -- (3.3565, 0) -- (3.637, -0.28125) -- (3.7776, 0) -- (3.637, 0.140625) -- (3.49675, 0) -- (3.637, -0.140625);
        \node[fill=white,inner sep=1.5mm,outer sep=1.5mm] at (3.637,-0.25)
        \coordinate[label=below:\small$L$] (L) at (3.637,0); \fill (L) circle (1pt);

        \draw[thick, pattern=dots] (3.637,0) circle [radius=1.9cm];
\end{tikzpicture}
    
    Omnis quia sint iste adipisci quis laudantium facere nostrum. Inventore non reiciendis eius nulla voluptatem ut pariatur. Eum aliquid eos est sed similique saepe. Voluptas qui dolor saepe aut aut delectus.

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\clip (-2.5,-4) rectangle (9.5, 4);` at the start of the picture, then adjust the numbers. No time to check, but it should work. (Funny way to add arrows... )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use clipping to achieve the effect you want. You can look that up in the official manual of TikZ.
In this case just add a line something like this at the beginning of your tikzpicture:

```
\clip (-2,-2) rectangle (9.5,5);
```

This will make sure that everything TikZ draws after that point is only visible if it is within the clip path (in this case a rectangle).

By the way: Your provided code contained some minor syntax errors.